# SQL Service Broker to notify external app

Tags: sql, service-broker

After much searching on Service Broker, I came across [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559581/how-to-notify-a-windows-servicec-of-a-db-table-changesql-2005):

My scenario is similar to the one mentioned there, in that I have a SQL trigger on a table, and in this trigger I'm calling xp_cmdshell to pass primary key information to an external exe.

I can see the value of setting up a Service Broker queue and service instead of using a trigger on a table. As I understand it, the activation sproc that I set up to process messages in the queue would now contain my call to xp_cmdshell.

However, I can't figure out how to hook up a "change to data in a table" event as the triggering event.  I would expect the `CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION` clause to have an `ON TABLE [x] FOR [INSERT|UPDATE]` part to it, but it does not.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288434/how-to-monitor-sql-server-table-changes-by-using-c/5288470#5288470

Comment: no it doesn't.  Initially I liked the idea of using SQLDependency a-la ASP.Net, but the problem with that is that it's OnChange event does not tell me what record in the db changed.

Comment: See here: http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559581/how-to-notify-a-windows-servicec-of-a-db-table-changesql-2005) you provided actually gives a great answer to your question. As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190427.aspx), event notification feature is really meant for DDL and database state changes. What you want is probably to stick with triggers, but make the xp_cmdshell call asynchronous. I really don't think any better answer can be provided than the one Remus gave to the linked question.