# How to write a trigger firing when someone made specific changes and saved on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, eventtrigger, xp-cmdshell

I am new to SQL triggers scripting. Right now, I want to write a trigger firing when someone modify a create or alter statement in table definition in SQL Server and saved.

Can someone please tell me what can make this happen and what kind of trigger should I research on?

So far I have only read some dml triggers tutorial and it's not quite alike to what I want.

Comment: Ddl triggers are what you need. Why the xp-cmdshell tag?

Comment: Because I want launch a .net program through cmd when the trigger is fired. Is there any alternative to do that?

Comment: In that case Service Broker and Event notifications are possibly more suitable.

Comment: Yes clr stored procedure well given you are on 2005 or later. Is this server under your control? xp_cmdShell is blocked by default.

Comment: Just found this answer which looks like it might be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1562066/73226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDL is my option to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406(v=sql.105).aspx